# Cloned Raspi Zero W boots into Emergency Mode

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, pi-zero-w

I have a Raspi (3+) that for whatever reason I need to clone to use as a temporary backup for downtime later on. After realising the effort needed to recreate it from scratch, I cloned its entire SD card to another with `dd if=/dev/mmblck0 of=/dev/sdb`, then did the usual steps to ensure uniqueness (hostname, static IP) wouldn't cause errors.

While the cloned SD boots, it boots into Emergency mode. I cannot use a keyboard to hit a `^D` and SSH naturally does not work. `tail`ing the `/var/log` files on the cloned SD on a different device only shows logs up to the clone op, so something indicates the new Pi might not be able to write to file. However, `fsck` shows no errors, and I can write to the SD from other devices.

Is this something I can fix via some analysis of the cloned SD card, or is (as I suspect) there some difference between 3+ and Zero W models that mean such a clone op won't cut it?

Comment: A up to date Raspbian image should work on any model. I am unfamiliar with "the usual steps to ensure uniqueness (hostname, static IP)". If the  Pi boots into Emergency mode the root FS will be in RO mode. remount it as read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

Comment: *I cloned its entire SD card to another with `dd if=/dev/mmblck0 of=/dev/sdb`* - I tried that once ... I think that's the only time I've seen "emergency mode" - i.e. I don't think running that command is going to produce a useful clone

Comment: [this looks like it could do the trick](https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone)

Comment: by the way, I'm trying the script in the above link right now - it's been 30 minutes (5GB used in my root partition) and it's done about 60% - so, it's slow - but then, the reason I'm doing this is because my SD card is slow to begin with, and this seems to be the best (safest) way to create an image of my current setup - I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: OK, it took 55 minutes for 5GB (again, my SD card was troublesome) and has resulted in a bootable clone

Comment: @JaromandaX Again, the same result for my device: no way of accessing logs for the point of failure near the end of the boot. Using `fsck` and checking `/etc/fstab` has not changed this, and there appears to be no read-write errors until quite late in the boot process.

Comment: Does the cloned card only have issues in the zero? Does the original card boot in the zero?

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't tell, unfortunately, as the original Pi is being used in a live environment. The SD cards are identical models, however. I will report back if I can find an alternate SD card, but I don't suspect that there are RW issues with it.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with a faulty sd card - especially if the rsync method didn't complain with any errors (dd would complain too) - it may be you've installed something that only runs on later PI's - I take it you can't take down the live environment for the 2 minutes it would take to see if the clone works

Comment: what happens if you plug the cloned card into the working RPi?

Comment: @jsotola - that's what I asked him to try - but two minutes "offline" is too much for him

Comment: You are saying the original is a live environment. But did you clone it offline ?

Comment: @onion I cloned the SD with `dd` and then again with `rpi-clone`, which can function while live.